# Determine the Mode when Divided by another column in Excel or Power Pivot

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerpivot

The question I am trying to answer is, what is the most common quantity of product X when it is sold with product Y? If each order only had 1 Product Y on it, I could use Excel's MODE.SNGL function. However, some orders have more than 1 Product Y. This means Product X has to be divided by Product Y, and the result needs to be counted by the quantity of Product Y to get the real mode. Here is a very simple example:

```
Order #  |  Product Y  |  Product X  
 111     |    1        |     2  
 123     |    2        |     4  
 145     |    1        |     1  
 354     |    1        |     1
```

In this example, the correct answer for the Mode of Product X is 2. Order 123 has 2 Product Y and 4 Product X, so in the Mode calculation, this should be counted as two 2s. When combined with Order 111, this makes three 2s and our mode.

Is there a formula in Excel or PowerPivot which I can use to get this result?

Comment: what have you tried so far, and how you would like to display the output?

Answer (score 0):

A worksheet formula `=MODE.SNGL(OrderTable[Product X]/OrderTable[Product Y])` would work.

### Revised answer

Let me withdraw the answer above. What OP is looking for was the mode of "Product X / Product Y", treating each individual *Product Y* as an observation, rather than each *Order*.

So, here is the DAX measure to calculate the desired number.

```
Most Frequent Number Of X Per Y = 
VAR OrdersXdivY = ADDCOLUMNS(
    Orders,
    "@X / Y", DIVIDE(Orders[Product X], Orders[Product Y])
)
VAR SumByXdivY = SUMMARIZE(
    OrdersXdivY,
    [@X / Y],
    "@Sum Y", SUM(Orders[Product Y])
)
RETURN SUMX(TOPN(1, SumByXdivY, [@Sum Y], DESC), [@X / Y])
```

Comment: unfortunately it won't work. If you add the following to Y: `10, 2` and the following to X: `10, 4`, your formula will return `2` but the correct answer should be `1` which has 12 occurrences while `2` only has 5 occurrences.

Comment: @TerryW thank you for the comment. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A regular formula might look like this:

```
=INDEX(C2:C5/B2:B5,MATCH(MAX(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(B2:B5)*(C2:C5/B2:B5=TRANSPOSE(C2:C5)/TRANSPOSE(B2:B5)),ROW(B2:B5)^0)),
MMULT(TRANSPOSE(B2:B5)*(C2:C5/B2:B5=TRANSPOSE(C2:C5)/TRANSPOSE(B2:B5)),ROW(B2:B5)^0),0))
```

Is an array formula and has to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]